# how can I show the record horizontally in view

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have  the following record in  a view horizontally. I cannot show the the exact layout here.  but I hope you can understand what I am looking for the help.
One record under in one column, another record in another column in same row , maximumn 6 column should be shown in each row that means 6 record in each row .
I have the following model

```
 public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Itemname { get; set; }
    public int QTY { get; set; }
}
```

In View I am using IEnumerable. I am trying to list in view the record horizontally in a table under td . maximum 6 record  in a row

---

### 01/01/2020
02/01/2020

Customer 1
Customer 2

---

Item1
Item2

Comment: How is your HTML looking like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap to specify the number of records per column, such as

```
<td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
```

and the following is my demo:

**Controller:**

```
public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        private readonly OrderContext _context;

        public OrderController(OrderContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Orders
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var model = new OrderList()
            {
                OrderLists = await _context.Orders.ToListAsync()
            };
            return View(model);
        }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Itemname { get; set; }
    public int QTY { get; set; }        
}
public class OrderList
{
    public IEnumerable<Order> OrderLists { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model OrderList

<table class="table">
    <tbody>       
            <tr class="row">
            @foreach (var item in Model.OrderLists)
                {
                <td class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OrderDate)<br />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer)<br />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Itemname) <br />
                </td>
                }           
            </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Result:

[image]